# How can I implement COMMIT and ROLLBACK in Oracle SQL using stored procedures?

Tags: sql

I am learning how to use stored procedures in `SQL` and I would like to know some ideas on how to `"emulate"`, actually, implement it as if Oracle didn't. Let's say I have the below tables and everytime I try to insert values into any of them, those values are inserted on an auxiliary table in order to keep them there until I call my procedure called: `EXECUTE COMMIT;`

- R1(a int, b varchar2, c double) R2(a int, c date)

Comment: I don't recommend doing this - given that Oracle supports transactions anyway, you would just be wasting your time as actual implementations of transactions are both a core part of the underlying database engine system and considerably more complicated. Consider how you would atomically insert a complicated relational insertion and update operation using existing rows? Your proposal doesn't work in that scenario.

Comment: I know, but it's something that doesn't have to be perfect. Just to do it as a class practice.

Comment: I have read many articles and they give hints like to use TRIGGERS, but I don't really know it very well.

Comment: My point is that this exercise wouldn't be a good practice for anything; it's a fool's errand, if you will. There are other and better ways to learn about RDBMS or Oracle internals.